# Check if containers have children and append to those that don't

Tags: javascript, append, containers

I'm trying to append an image to one of 8 containers without having to code in which one I want. I want it to be able to see which containers are empty and append to those. I have coded something up that I thought would have worked but it only appends to the 8th container, even though the other 7 are empty. It also seems like there could be a much better way to do it

```
    if (beatcontainer1.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer2}
    if (beatcontainer2.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer3}
    if (beatcontainer3.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer4}
    if (beatcontainer4.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer5}
    if (beatcontainer5.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer6}
    if (beatcontainer6.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer7}
    if (beatcontainer7.firstChild){
        currentbeat = beatcontainer8}
    
currentbeat.appendChild(qnotec)
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if there is actual code to critique/test but if you use ELSE in your IF statements above that might help.

Comment: You might consider a loop that iterates through each container and appends to the empty ones. I agree that it would help to include [relevant HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I feel what you are looking for is an "if-else" clause.

You only need to check the other if clauses if your first one fails.

So you can try something like this.

```
if (beatcontainer1.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer2}
else if (beatcontainer2.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer3}
else if (beatcontainer3.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer4}
else if (beatcontainer4.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer5}
else if (beatcontainer5.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer6}
else if (beatcontainer6.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer7}
else if (beatcontainer7.firstChild){
    currentbeat = beatcontainer8}

currentbeat.appendChild(qnotec)
```

Does this work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in an array and find the first that matches your condition:

```
const containers = [
  beatcontainer1,
  beatcontainer2,
  beatcontainer3,
  beatcontainer4,
  // ...
]

const matchingContainer = containers.find((container) => container.firstChild)
matchingContainer.appendChild(qnotec)
```

Notice that I just copied your condition, if you are looking for an empty node, this doesn't seem the right condition. Something like this would do though:

```
const emptyContainer = containers.find((container) => !container.hasChildNodes())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess at the structure of your HTML, or maybe recommending a structure based on your question. Here, we find all `<div>` elements that are in the `beatContainers` container. When we come across one that is empty, we make sure we haven't already appended an element (checking for `found`) - then append the element and then set the flag `found` to true.

```js
let found = false ;
let qnotec = document.querySelector('.appendme');
 document.querySelectorAll('.beatContainers div').forEach( cell => { 
    if (cell.innerHTML =='' && !found) {
       cell.appendChild(qnotec)
       found=true;
    }
  })
```

```html
<div class='appendme'>Insert this</div>

<div class='beatContainers'>
<div>something</div>
<div></div>
<div>something</div>
<div>something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be a solution, including an explanation helps to improve the quality of your post. Consider that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.